# Webpage for both tablet and PC

Tags: website-design

Can we develop webpages that will work on both tablet, say Android, and Desktops/PCs (here I'm looking at non flash based web pages). Since I was looking at Sencha, do we need to use both Sencha Architect and Sencha Touch for the above development requirement?

Any other better alternatives?

Answer (score 4):

The answer is yes, you can. Assuming you're building the website from scratch rather than using a content management system then basing your site around something like the Twitter Bootstrap framework http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/ will likely give you the flexibility you're looking for.

If you want the website to feel exactly like a mobile app on a mobile device then generally you either need two versions of your site or a system which utilizes mobile or desktop templates depending on the requesting browser (all web scripting languages can be used to do this but it's extract design work).

You can build a 'mobile first' design using something like Sencha Touch (webkit browsers only) or the more cross platform jQuery Mobile framework: http://jquerymobile.com/

Comment: Just a note: "mobile first" is more the strategy from starting to think from the mobile device first, rather than making use of a mobile framework (than in turn you would be in the two-version-situation you noted in the 2nd paragraph).

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering if we can have jquerymobile for creating a webpage that will work on Desktop as well as a Tablet.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want: You could create a website that works well for many clients e.g. by applying the concept of [Responsive Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_Web_Design). For the fun of it, got to the site of [Sylvester Stallone](http://sylvesterstallone.com/) and resize your browser window to see how the page adapts.

Or you create a website with a strong focus on the mobile (or tablet) device that looks like a native app - then use frameworks like that from Sencha or JQuery Mobile. In this case you go the route of creating something like a Web Application but not a website for the average visitor.
For Sencha: You don't need Architect but it will help you speed up the interface part.

Another way would be a combination, let's say you have Wordpress, choose a Theme that uses responsive layout and install a plugin that delivers another themed variant of the page just for mobile devices.